# Can't show array values in console log outisde of loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I push array outside loop with (cpu_usage, timestamp and clientID).Now i want to read on console log values of clientID `console.log(result[0][2]);` .But it shows me a error "Cannot read property '2' of undefined". Is someone knows where is a problem ? Also if i call this array inside loop it works

content of array: [image: content of array]
error after i used `console.log(result[0][2]);` [image: error]

```
<div id="cont"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">

$.getJSON( "http://localhost:8000/api/devices", function( res) {


    var result= [];
    var devNames = new Array();
console.log(result[0][2]);
  $.each( res, function(i) {
        var deviceNames=data[i].clientAllias;
        var clientId=data[i].clientId;
        devNames .push(deviceNames);        
    $.each( res[i].clientData, function(a) {
        $.each( res[i].clientData[a], function(key, val) {
            clientId2=res[i].clientData[a].clientId
            var cpu=res[i].clientData[a].cpuUsage;
            var time_usages=res[i].clientData[a].timestamp;
            final=[];
            final.push(time_usages, cpu, clientId2);
            result.push(final);

  });
  });
     });

    result.sort();



$(document).ready(function(){
        var Object = {
            marker: {
        states: {
            enabled: true,
        }
    },
        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: 'Sec'
            }, {
                count: 1,
                type: 'hour',
                text: 'Min'
            }, 
            {
                count: 1,
                type: 'day',
                text: 'Hours'
            },

            {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'

            }],
            title:'hours',
            inputEnabled: true,
            _selected: 1
        },


            title: {
                text: clientNames,
            },
          xAxis: {

    title: {
        enabled: true,
        text: 'CPU USAGE'
    },
    type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
               second: '%H:%M:%S',
               minute: '%H:%M',
               hour: '%H:%M',


            },


},
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false,

            }
        }
    },

            series: [{
    name:"CPU USAGE",
   data: result,
    }],

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'cont'
            }

        };

         var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(dataObject);   
        //var chart = $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', dataObject);



    });
   });




</script>
```

Comment: result is an empty array. Why are you reading[0][1] of it? Did you mean to read the ajax returned result that would be the data variable

Comment: Yes i want to read this data [1533753914808, 0.1530477108998466, 9458] which i  have in console log.For example 9458

Comment: You also have Bootstrap js added before jQuery, that is also throwing an error, move jQuery to top of includes

Comment: where in your code are you trying to log `console.log(result[0][2]);` I don't see it in your code above.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it just bellow **var clientNames = new Array();** . And this error "Cannot read property '2' of undefined i get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re console logging at the wrong spot. There’s nothing in **result** when you’re logging so it errors out when you try to access a nested element.

Put the console log at the end (after **result.sort()**) and you should get what you need